# Issue after regenerating xrm.cs

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, code-generation, xrm

**ISSUE:**

I am using `Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011`. I have added an extension (Customer Service Contacts) to our CRM.

I need to make some respective changes to UI as well. For that, I started my changes with **regeneration of XRM.cs**.

I have done following as a part of that:

```
C:\Users\<userName>\SDK\Bin>CrmSvcUtil.exe 
/codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization,    
Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration" /out:\Xrm003.cs 
/url:http://<url_for_server>/<organization_name>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
/domain:"<domain_name>" /username:"<username>" /password:"<password>" 
/namespace:<desired_namespace_name> /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

This helped me regenerate the `Xrm003.cs`. But, when I am comparing this newly generated Xrm003.cs with the already existing one, I can see some differences in the entities which I have not touched at all.

Following are some of those:

Original one had:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Drop-down list for selecting the category of the account.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("accountcategorycode")]
    public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue AccountCategoryCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue>("accountcategorycode");
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("AccountCategoryCode");
            this.SetAttributeValue("accountcategorycode", value);
            this.OnPropertyChanged("AccountCategoryCode");
        }
    }
```

The new one has:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Drop-down list for selecting the category of the account.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("accountcategorycode")]
    public System.Nullable<int> AccountCategoryCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetAttributeValue<System.Nullable<int>>("accountcategorycode");
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue>("AccountCategoryCode", "accountcategorycode", value);
        }
    }
```

If you notice the differences, you will see 2 things:

1. Type of `AccountCategoryCode` is `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue` (in the original) and `System.Nullable<int>` in the regenerated.
2. The way `set` is implemented.

This is for many other entities as well.

Can anyone please let me know why is this because of or have I missed any step in regeneration of XRM.cs? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
One thing, which might be the cause(?) is: We had applied Rollup 16 to CRM inbetween these 2 XRM.cs.

---

**SOLUTION TO RESOLVE ISSUE:**

Please refer answer by Daryl, which I have marked as an answer.

I followed what he said and did changes to my XRM.cs regeneration command as follows (following one is the appropriate command, which helped me to resolve my issue):

```
C:\Users\<userName>\SDK\Bin>CrmSvcUtil.exe 
/out:\Xrm003.cs 
/url:http://<url_for_server>/<organization_name>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
/domain:"<domain_name>" /username:"<username>" /password:"<password>" 
/namespace:<desired_namespace_name> /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

**Conclusion:**

I had following in my command which was causing issue that I have mentioned in my Q:

```
/codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization,    
Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration"
```

My issue was resolved just by removing it.

Comment: did you update the sdk?

Comment: @GuidoPreite, Actually, I am not sure when the original `XRM.cs` was generated and which SDK was used for that. I have my current SDK installed almost 5 months back.

Comment: @GuidoPreite, I just now noticed that I have installed `Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK` instead of 2011. Let me try installing appropriate one.

Comment: @GuidoPreite, Thanks for your suggestion. I installed Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK and regenerated using it. But, still I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some custom code generation in there with whatever `"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization,Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration"` is.  I'm guessing this is what has changed.  It almost looks like this has been changed to run in Windows RT, since it [doesn't support the property changing events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2014/09/08/new-sample-code-for-dynamics-crm-mobile-development-on-windows-8.aspx).

Have you tried the [EarlyBound Generator](https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I referred: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695790(v=crm.5).aspx#generate and tried accordingly. But, it seems that what you are telling me might be the reason.

Comment: @Vikram, has what your entities inherit from changed?  What is the full class name (namespace included) that they inherit from?  Has that changed?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I think, your original answer helped me to get through. Doing some testing on the regenerated XRM.cs. I will let you know whether that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Daryl, Thank you very much! I confirmed my XRM.cs. It is the way I want (just the entities have been reordered, hence difficult to compare with the already existing one in the file of almost 200k lines!). I have modified my Q with the appropriate answer...all thanks to you!

Comment: @Vikram the EarlyBound Generator that I mentioned in my answer will order the entities and optionsets it generates alphabetically.  Give it a try!